# How to rank groups of data?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.4

Given the following, and tasked with ranking the raw data by the SUM(volume) within each group:

```
group_id    volume
1           2
1           3
2           5
3           1
3           3
```

How can I obtain the following?

```
group_id    volume  group_volume    rank
1           2       5               1
1           3       5               1
2           5       5               2
3           1       4               3
3           3       4               3
```

I can get `group_volume` easily, but am struggling on how to break the ties in rank without grouping by + ranking in a separate subquery and joining in.

```sql
SELECT *
, SUM(volume) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) AS grouped_volume
, ... AS rank
FROM groups
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two levels of window functions for this:

```
select g.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by group_volume desc, group_id) as rank
from (select g.*,
             sum(volume) over (partition by group_id) as group_volume
      from groups g
     ) g;
```

There is no need for a `JOIN`.

Comment: This will give incorrect result you have use either `order by  group_id, group_volume` or `order by group_volume desc, group_id`

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE and Dense_rank

```
WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT group_id, volume, 
              sum(volume) over(partition by group_id) group_volume
from table1)
SELECT A.*, dense_rank() over( order by  group_id, group_volume) rank FROM CTE1 A;
```